# Can I update NGINX version in Azure AKS Cluster?

Tags: nginx, azure-aks, azure-machine-learning-service

Hopefully, I'm posting this in the right place. We have a ML team using an Azure AKS cluster which was built by me. Because this is all built around ML Studio I figured this might be the best place to ask for a dev viewpoint.

A recent security scan identified several open ports on the nodes and workloads which identify themselves as runnning NGINX v1.10.3:

```
[root ~]# curl 10.210.100.62:32570 -ik
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)
Date: Wed, 09 Mar 2022 14:19:55 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 7
Connection: keep-alive
```

The cluster is strictly used to host ML Studio inference endpoints.

The open ports running NGINX are:

```
5001
31366
31419
32570
```

I'm pretty sure 5001 is the listening port on all the inference endpoints, so I imagine it might have something to do with the ML Studio and how it deploys the inference endpoints. The other ports are probably some control ports on the Kubernetes nodes?

I tried updating the kubernetes version on the control plain and nodes. But this didn't make any difference to the running NGINX version, even on the nodes. I connected to one of the hosts in a root shell, but the environment is really stripped and I didn't get very far in trying to identify where NGINX is running from or if it is even possible to update. I suspect attempting to do so in a shell can only break things.

Does anybody know if it is even possible to update this in anyway?

Answer (score 2):

It seems you exposed your app with a ServiceType `NodePort` and the Nginx is inside your container as you did not mentioned any ingress.

Maybe re-check the image build (Dockerfile). There you should be able to update the nginx.

I would also recommend to never use [NodePort](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#type-nodeport). As you recognized by yourself it opens ports directly on each node which is kinda an insecure configuration.

Better always use an [ingress-controller](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress-controllers/). [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/ingress-basic?tabs=azure-cli) you can find a documentation from the Microsoft Docs to create a basic ingress-controller. You would then only expose the ingress-controller that becomes the single entry point to your cluster (doenst matter if public or private). The last piece are [ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/) resources to make your application accessible.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Yes, this seems like the better choice and puts the "public" facing endpoint under my control. Admittedly, this was one of those "dev" PoC projects that was NEVER supposed to go in to production for any lengthy period of time. So, the end goal is to move or rebuild this environment. Still wondering if there is any direct explanation for why what appears to be a current node image is using such an outdated version of NGINX, apart from the workload itself, which uses the same outdated version. And if it can be updated.

Comment: its is nether the node nor AKS...the nginx is backed into your container image...so check the image build process to update the nginx version or better just remove nginx from the container image